# Mamp phpMyAdmin - Cannot connect: invalid settings

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, mamp

When trying to connect to phpmyadmin/mysql using Mamp I get the error:

```
Cannot connect: invalid settings.
```

I haven't changed the root username or password. (root/root)

Please let me know if I can get some information to help out with the debugging.

Comment: "I" is capital on English.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're having a problem like this: [Cannot connect to phpMyAdmin on MAMP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38353489/cannot-connect-to-phpmyadmin-on-mamp)

If so, in MAMP Preferences switch PHP 7 to 5.6.10. That fixed the issue for me. Thanks to @rmaspero for the original answer!