# Cannot connect to phpMyAdmin on MAMP

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, mamp

Im getting this error message:

MySQL said:

Cannot connect: invalid settings. 
phpMyAdmin tried to connect to the MySQL server, and the server rejected the connection. You should check the host, username and password in your configuration and make sure that they correspond to the information given by the administrator of the MySQL server.

The user and pass are the default ones - both 'root'. I haven't set them anywhere. Ive tried various answers on here but nothing is working

Comment: Are you running phpMyAdmin on the same server? Do you have the correct hostname? Can you connect locally?

Comment: Im working locally yes Jonny. The MAMP startup page appears when I connect to servers. I get two green lights. Its only when I click on phpMyAdmin I get the error. I checked 'config.inc.php' and it has these details:
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user']          = 'root';    
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password']      = 'root';  

which is the same as always whenever Ive installed MAMP. I haven’t changed, or been asked for any login details at any point during or after installation. Ive never needed to before. Thanks

Comment: So the command line client for mysql works?
Have you set it up to use localhost?

Comment: Sorry Jonny - Im not very knowledgeable on this. How do I check the command line client for mysql? Ive simply installed mamp from the dmg file with all the default settings. I didnt change anything

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Preferences pane of MAMP switch back from PHP 7 to 5.6.10 and it should work again.

Comment: Perfect - that fixed the problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I was having the same problem, tried all these suggestions but nothing worked. So I did the only thing I could think off, restarted the machine...started MAMP, mysql server was off, so I just hit start server and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

/Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/phpMyAdmin/config.inc.php

Try changing the $cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] from "localhost" to "127.0.0.1"

Comment: This helped me but instead of phpMyAdmin the directory is phpMyAdmin5 depending of the version of MAMP you have.

Answer (score 0):

None of these solutions worked for me. To fix this I opened up MAMP's httpd.conf, searched for "phpmyadmin" and came across a different path to phpmyadmin at `/Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/phpMyAdmin`. Once I edited the `phpmyadmin/config.inc.php` file at this location so the user was no longer "mamp" but "root" I was then able to launch phpmyadmin as expected. I know this question is old but hopefully this helps someone!

Comment: Cheers.
I hadn't updated MAMP Pro for a while and had forgotten this little hack.
For me, the change was to config.inc.php in the phpMyAdmin5 folder.